# Python cx_Freeze error "No module named 'cx_Freeze.util'"

Tags: python

When I run `setup.py build`, I get the error mentioned in the title above.

Here is my code:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(
    name="testing",
    version="3.1",
    description="test",
    executables = [Executable("client.py",base="Win32GUI")])
```

I am running Python 3.4.

Answer (score 4):

I am using python v3.6. I have solved the problem by installing upgrade for cx_freez issue following command to python

```
    python -m pip install cx_Freeze --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check to make sure you have a version of cx_Freeze installed that works with Python 3.4, I have had that error once and this was the problem.

Have you tried using from cx_Freeze import *?

Comment: I installed cx_Freeze-5.0.win32-py3.4.exe from pypi

Comment: And yes with the suggestion you said I still get the same error

Comment: Okay, I'll look into it some more!

Comment: Please do, I need this fixed asap!

Comment: FIXED! I moved onto pyinstaller instead

Comment: Okay, I was going to ask for more information but you have solved it yourself! Looking for another package that does the same thing is a good way to go!